# Facebook like button (error written in red)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-like

I created an application and I wanted to add a like button.

When I click the button, it changes to show that I like the page, then immediately changes back with a red "Error" next to it.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=453976824647366";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


       <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/453976824647366/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

This is a page index.php.

This is also my application settings, it might be of some help for you to understand my problem.

[image: My aplication settings]

After the user "likes" the application, I want to redirect him on a second page (located in the root of my project).

Comment: And you're using `localhost`?

Comment: For testing yes, but other users can't access it.

Comment: But I don't think you can use the like feature ...

Comment: this is just a test.i just want to redirect to another page when i click the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like boxes are meant to like a certain existing content that has a valid URL.

In your case you can test some functions but not like box.

For a best approach I would suggest you to move you website online can continue testing from there.

Read '[What happens when I click a Like or Recommend button on external websites?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=130849170326225)'

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can i move my application online to continue testing ? ( i'm an absolute beginner with Facebook, php )

Comment: Get a host or use your direct IP as website. For example if your Internet Provider gives you an public IP you can test directly with that, eg: http://113.36.35.12/index.php

Comment: I don't have a public IP, would you recommend a particular free host please ?

Comment: I cannot do that, it depends on your country to have "faster" connections, try with Google "PHP hosting *country*"